# Split the array and get value [React native]

Tags: arrays, react-native, split

I am developing the react native application and I want to split the array but I can't understand how to do that,

```
[{"dtCreatedOn": "2021-06-01T03:28:21.450Z", "flgIsActive": true, "inTagId": 2, "stTags": "Song"}, "3", "6", "7", "8"]
```

I have something like the above array, I want to get the value of the **inTagId** and also last integer value **"3", "6", "7", "8"**  from this array

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [{"dtCreatedOn": "2021-06-01T03:28:21.450Z", "flgIsActive": true, "inTagId": 2, "stTags": "Song"}, "3", "6", "7", "8"]

var tagID  = a[0].inTagId

var b = Object.keys(a)
var lastInteger = b[(b.length-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test =  [{"dtCreatedOn": "2021-06-01T03:26:44.910Z", "flgIsActive": true, "inTagId": 1, "stTags": "Emotion"},"4","5","6"]    
var tags = [];
test.map(function(ele) {
     if(typeof ele === 'object')
     {
        tags.push(ele.inTagId);
     }
     else
     {
         tags.push(ele)
     }
});

tags.join(',')
```